# How i can import TFS repository to Github?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, tfs, repository

I have a repository who's I'm creating in Visual Studio Team Services and I'd like to clone this repo and connect with visual studio. I have a problem when I try ti import repo to github. I have a message so invalid url(i copy link from clone button in VSTS). In VS I have an error.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can refer to this article to import repository from VSTS to GitHub by using Alternate authentication credentials. ([Importing a repository with GitHub Importer](https://help.github.com/articles/importing-a-repository-with-github-importer/))

Secondly, you can push the source to GitHub via Visual Studio directly.

1. Connect to your repository of VSTS and go to Home (Click Home icon in Team explorer)
2. Click Settings > Repository Settings
3. Click Add in Remotes section

[image]

4. Specify Name, Fetch and Push URL (clone your github repository url)
5. Go to Sync view of team explorer
6. Click Push link
7. Select repository name you added (step 3, 4) and branch
8. Click Push

[image]